# xna texture coordinates

Tags: c#, xna, coordinates, textures

I've been trying to combine a couple of [riemers](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/xnacsharp.php) tutorials to make a terrain that is textured and lit. I'm almost there but I can't get the application of the texture right. I believe the problem is in SetUpVertices() with the setting of the texture coordinates. I know currently the code reads that they're all set to (0, 0) and I need to have it so that they are set to the corners of the texture but I can't seem to get the code right. Anybody out there able to assist?

```
private void SetUpVertices()
{
    vertices = new VertexPositionNormalTexture[terrainWidth * terrainHeight];
    for (int x = 0; x < terrainWidth; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < terrainHeight; y++)
        {
            vertices[x + y * terrainWidth].Position = new Vector3(x, -y, heightData[x, y]);
            vertices[x + y * terrainWidth].TextureCoordinate.X = 0;
            vertices[x + y * terrainWidth].TextureCoordinate.Y = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I've added the full code of Game1.cs to this pastie http://pastebin.com/REd8QDZA

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Considering that tags are relevant to the content of the post isn't it inevitable that titles will contain them if the title itself is to be relevant too?

Comment: No, it's not. Please read that link. If the tags are relevant to the question, then place them in the tags area. If they are not relevant to the question, then please don't use them.

Comment: I read the post and I will certainly try to do as you suggest in the future if it makes things more productive but I still don't see the reasoning. Taking this instance as an example I should have worded it as an actual question but the question "How do I set texture coordinates in xna using c#?" still contains all the tags. How do I ask it without using them. I'm not trying to be facetious, just curious.

Comment: It's not so much about not duplicating some text. It's more about not taking a good title, then tacking on some tags. If you're using "C#" as part of a good title, then go ahead. The problem is when you have a title like "xna texture coordinates", and add "C#" or "(C#)" at the start or end, just so we know the question is about C#. _That's_ what the tags are for.

Comment: I think I'm on the same page now. Thank you John.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stretch the texture across the surface by interpolating from 0 to 1:

```
vertices[x + y * terrainWidth].TextureCoordinate.X = x / (terrainWidth - 1.0);
vertices[x + y * terrainWidth].TextureCoordinate.Y = y / (terrainHeight - 1.0);
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple like that but I just couldn't get it right. I've been on it for days! I love you, :)

Comment: I've noticed that when I scale the terrain up that the texture is stretched over the entire terrain. What I was hoping to achieve was the texture added to each of the triangles. Thanks for the help that you've given already but could I trouble you for another suggestion?

Comment: @luigivampa You'd need to assign the texture as you wnat, from 0 - 1.  If you want it to repeat, just go <0 and >1.

Comment: Sorry Reed, you've lost me (I'm a gardener not a programmer!). I understand that 0,0 is top left and 1,1 is bottom right of the texture but how do I apply that as code? I've tried dozens of variations trying to assign the coordinates properly but generally it just appears smudged.